# correct content type header is i am Uploading url encoded string using Webclient with UTF8 encoding

Tags: asp.net, .net, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working on an asp.net MVC web application, and i am integrating with a 3rd party API. now the 3rd party API , requires the following for the JSON object:-

- To URL encode the json object. to be able to pass values such as `500%600` , `123%456`...
- to use UTF8 encoding to be able to pass non-ASCII characters such as `£` , `¬`..

so i have the following `WebClient()` `UploadString()` method , which will url encode the passed json object and defining UTF8 encoding :-

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
                {
                    string url = currentURL + "resources?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                    var urlencodedData= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data);
                    crudoutput = wc.UploadString(uri, "INPUT_DATA=" +urlencodedData );
                }
```

so in my case i am using both url encoded data and UTF8 encoding.. so not sure why content type header i should be using ?? is the one i am using correct:-

```
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

or i need to specify UTF8 encoding inside it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer encoding is already set with the `Encoding` property of the web client. How ever some of the UTF-8 specific characters may require specific transformations based on the encoding. For that reason the [`UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/h10z5byc.aspx) method has a overload that accepts a encoding.

You simply use that method like this:

```
var urlencodedData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

The content type you selected controls only how the content payload is interpreted. If you want to use key and value pairs with URL encoded values, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the content type you should use.

How ever if you want to transfer a JSON payload you should use the content type `application/json` as specified by [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). In case you choose to do that, you can omit the URL encoding and the `"INPUT_DATA="`.

Comment: Based on my test if i specify the content type header as "application/json" and i do not explicitly url encode my json,, then if my json object contain values such as 500%600 ,, they are going to be saved as 500`0 inside the external system,, which means that API is somehow url decoding the json object once it receive it ... so that why i chose to do things as i shown in my code.. now what you are saying is the correct appraoch assuming the external API will look at the content type and do the decode  accordingly ...

Comment: ....but the external API have some problems... so is my appraoch valid ? or might cause problems ? also the INPUT_DATA is just part of the whole json string it is not a key & value pairs so i need to add it  .. and if i removes it , i will get an error from the external API that the json string is invalid !!

Comment: Well always assuming that your counter part handles requests according to the standards. The `INPUT_DATA=` is **never** part of the JSON data. JSON data identifies key-value pairs by `Key: Value` and it always sends objects like: `{ Key: Value, Key: Value}` The `INPUT_DATA=` is the key of the form encoding. If your target only supports that, you have to use it.

Comment: i know that json should never start with INPUT_DATA but this is how the json is being handled !! so returning back to my original question.. what is the correct content type to use in my case? thanks..

Comment: and this what i am using is this correct ? so no need to specify that i am using UTF8 encoding ? BTW here is a sample of the json i should be sending:- INPUT_DATA={"operation":{
      "Details":{
         "RESOURCENAME":"Windows Server",
         "ACCOUNTNAME":"Administrator",
         "RESOURCETYPE":"Windows",
         "PASSWORD":"Test123#@!",
         "NOTES":"Testing API",
         "RESOURCEURL":"http://windowsserver/adminconsole",
         "OWNERNAME":"admin",
         "RESOURCECUSTOMFIELD":[
          {"CUSTOMLABEL":"Secure Resource",
           "CUSTOMVALUE":"YES" } ]}}}

Comment: The encoding is usually not part of the content part. The webclient should add the encoding information properly on it's own because you set it with this line: `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`